# Dictionary not printing correctly

Tags: python, dictionary

Either dictionary input not working correctly or printing procedure not working successfully, unsure which and how to fix.

```
def ClassCall():
    global classes
    global Classdict
    global Classopen
    global students
    global people
    try:
        classes = input("Which class would you like to view? ")
        if classes == 1 or classes == 2 or classes == 3:
            print "Thank you"
            Classopen = open("Student" + "class" + str(classes) + ".csv","rb")
            Classfile = csv.reader(Classopen)
            Classdict = {}
            for people in Classfile:
                students = people[0]
                studentvalue = str(people[1])
                if students in Classdict:
                    Classdict[students].append(studentvalue)
                else :
                     Classdict[students] = [studentvalue]
        else:
            print "Enter a valid calss"
            ClassCall()
    except:
        print "This class is currently not added"
        ClassCall()
    ClassCall()

    global x
    x = 1
    while x == 1: 
        Question = raw_input("""How would you like to view the class?
    A) By Average, highest to lowest:
    B) By Highest score, highest to lowest:
    C) By Alphaetical order:
    """)
    Question = Question.title()
    if Question == "A" :
        for key, value in Classdict.items():
            Avg = sum(map(int, value))/ float(len(value))
            global AvgDict
            AvgDict = {}
            students = people[0]
            if key in AvgDict:
                AvgDict[key].append[Avg]
            else:
                AvgDict[key] = Avg
            print AvgDict
        Classopen.close()
        x = x + 1
        qtwo()

def qtwo(): 
    Questiontwo = raw_input("""How would you like to view it?
    A)By highest score, highest to lowest:
    B)By Alphaetical order:
    """)
    for key,value in Classdict.items():
        Questiontwo = Questiontwo.title()
        if Questiontwo == "A":
            print "You selected highest score, highest to lowest"
            sortedavghigh = sorted(AvgDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
            print sortedavghigh[::-1]
        elif Questiontwo == "B":
            print "You selected to sort it alphabetically"
            sortedavgapha = sorted(AvgDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
            print sortedavgalpha
```

This code yields this and won't print the whole of the average dictionary, however if I print it next to the averaging code it works fine. I however cannot do this because it needs to be sorted again

```
You selected highest score, highest to lowest
[('tom', 3.0)]
You selected highest score, highest to lowest
[('tom', 3.0)]
You selected highest score, highest to lowest
[('tom', 3.0)]
>>>
```

Comment: I tried running your code and it didn't print anything. Kindly provide a [mcve].

Comment: The last line should be `sortedavgapha`, not `sortedavgalpha`. (you miss a `l`)

Comment: And `ClassCall()` keeps calling itself (Just after except)